# XCode 4.3 codesign failed

Tags: iphone, code-signing, xcode4.3

H e l l o Everyone, after installing the last Xcode 4.3.1 I stuck with submitting apps. I can't archive apps for submitting. It says:

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains   disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/YYYYYY/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX002-ekjbelaglwpkredizicvazolomgj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ZZZZ/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ZZZZ.app/ZZZZ
AssertMacros: message,  file: /SourceCache/codesign_wrapper_Sim/Security-1245/codesign_wrapper/codesign_wrapper.c, line: 495
AssertMacros: profile,  file: /SourceCache/codesign_wrapper_Sim/Security-1245/codesign_wrapper/codesign_wrapper.c, line: 904
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: /Users/YYYYYY/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX002-ekjbelaglwpkredizicvazolomgj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ZZZZ/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ZZZZ.app/embedded.mobileprov
- (null)
```

I've tried to put in provisioning profiles (renew them), but it does not help.
There is no such a warring during normal build, only during archiving. In organizer when I press renew it gets only developers provisioning profiles and not renewing ones for distribution. So I put the distribution profile manually.

I've tried also to fix the project - Code sign identity - putting there iPhone distributing provisioning profile, remove build and clean targets, remove DerivedData (just in case) like people advised and cleaning all targets and checked twice that certificate is not expired.

Fortunately I kept the previous version of XCode 4.2, and it works fine archiving the same project. But I would love to hear any suggestions how to make XCode 4.3 working. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly this problem last night and was tearing my hair out!

However, the clue is that the last line "Failed to load provision profile" has characters missing from the end ('mobileprov' instead of 'mobileprovision').  Mine did too.  I think there's a character limit per line and if your directory or application name is too long it will fail to work properly.

I re-created the project with a shorter name and everything worked fine (after re-doing the provisioning, etc.).

Since that was my first app (and it was painful to submit!) this is a stab in the dark as to what the real cause is - so perhaps the more advanced users out there could tell me if I'm right or not?  Or was the re-creation of the project more likely to have fixed the issue?

Richard

Comment: Yes, you are right, Richard, when I renamed the app name to shorter one - this warning disappeared! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I changed the Archive Name under the Schema instead, but that fixed the problem, thanks!